# browser action icon is not shown in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

This my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "description": "Appliation",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "phone16.png", "256": "phone256.png" },
    "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "action description",
   "default_icon": "phone20.png"
}
}
```

But when install this extension browser action icon is not shown.
Is there any problem?
Hoe can I show?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this Manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Appliation",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test",
        "default_icon": "images/phone19.png",
    },
    "icons": { 
        "19": "images/phone19.png", 
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should one try this manifest ? What it the reason for `web_accessible_resources`, redundant `permissions` (which introduce unnecessary security holes for the user), a popup (when OP probably doesn't want one) and and an `options_page` that probably is not included in OP's extension files ? (Not to forget about the wrong `icons` sizes !)

Answer (score 0):

You are declairing a Chrome App,  not an extension:

```
"app": {
    ...
}
```

Change the above block to:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

(I.e. remove the wrapping `app` property, just leave `background`.)